# Threading issue when calling same function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to create 4 instances of a given function but having trouble working out how the function called knows which thread has called it.

This is in my header file:

```
// GPIO PINS stored within structs, for each sonic range finder.
typedef struct sonicPins {
    // front left pins.
    int trig1;
    int echo1;
    // front right pins.
    int trig2;
    int echo2;
    // rear left pins.
    int trig3;
    int echo3;
    // rear right pins.
    int trig4;
    int echo4;
} args;

void* setup(void *pinsPtr);
extern int threadFunc();
```

This is within my C file.

```
int threadFunc()
{
    struct sonicPins * pins;
    pthread_create(&pt1, NULL, setup, (void*) pins);
    pthread_create(&pt2, NULL, setup, (void*) pins);
    pthread_create(&pt3, NULL, setup, (void*) pins);
    pthread_create(&pt4, NULL, setup, (void*) pins);
    return 1;
}
```

The duty of the snippet below is to set pin value and run operations to manage a sensor. Each sensor is has its own echo and trigger values which are integers.

```
void* setup(void *pinsPtr)
{
    struct sonicPins *ptr = pinsPtr;
    int trig = 0, Echo = 0;

    printf("thread id %d\n", pt1);
    if (pt1 == 1993737328) {
        trig = ptr->trig1;
        Echo = ptr->echo1;
    } else if (pt2 == 1986323568) {
        trig = ptr->trig2;
        Echo = ptr->trig2;
    } else if (pt3 == 1977164912) {
        trig = ptr->trig3;
        Echo = ptr->trig3;
    } else if (pt4 == 4) {
        trig = ptr->trig4;
        Echo = ptr->echo4;
    }
    …other work…
}
```

I am new to C and did forget a thread ID isn't always the same, but I'm not sure what I can use to base the handling on.  Can you suggest something?

Comment: Why not create your own thread identification for example `1, 2, 3, 4` and pass it in with args?

Comment: You pass the same uninitialized pointer to the function each time you invoke `pthread_create()`; that is not going to lead to happiness.  You could pass a null pointer if you don't care, but in practice, you should pass a separate data structure each time containing the control information that the function needs to operate.  There's no other way for the function to know what it is supposed to do.  That is what the argument to the function is for.  And don't try reusing the same variable for each call — the scheduling is not predictable.

Comment: Which pointer is null?

Comment: @JamesSmith - This pointer `struct sonicPins * pins;`, where is it pointing? Nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an array of structs, where each struct has one echo and trigger value. Then you pass a different array entry to each thread, so that each thread only knows its own echo and trigger values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct sonicPins {
    int trig;
    int echo;
} sonicPins;

void *threadFunc( void *args )
{
    sonicPins *pins = args;
    printf( "trig=%d echo=%d\n", pins->trig, pins->echo );
    return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    pthread_t threadID[4];
    sonicPins pinsArray[4] = { { 1, 2 }, { 4, 8 }, { 16, 32 }, { 64, 128 } };

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        if ( pthread_create( &threadID[i], NULL, threadFunc, &pinsArray[i] ) != 0 )
            fprintf( stderr, "pthread_create failed: %d\n", i );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        pthread_join( threadID[i], NULL );
}
```

Comment: Okay I understand dunno why I didn't think of using 2D array before. The way I think my code should run wouldn't have the threads stopping as the sensors need to remain active at all times.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I guess the initializer makes it look like a 2D array.

Comment: Yeah sort of when I try as suggested it its saying doesn't know what sonicPins is where you have sonicPins pinsArray[4]; sonicThread.c:7:5: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
sonicThread.c:7:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
sonicThread.c:8:5: error: unknown type name ‘sonicPins’

Comment: It's 2015, why are you using a compiler that defaults to C90?

Comment: That's what is set to by default I guess never told it to use it. fixed the error by adding struct at the front of it

Comment: Thank you for your help its very much appreciated its certainly a big leap from Java down to C. PS should I have the threads stop and start even though the senors has to be running from start up to shutdown?

Comment: @JamesSmith  The threads can run for as long as you wish them to. In my example, the threads had nothing to do after printing the arguments, so I allowed them to return. The `main` function calls `pthread_join` so as not to exit too soon. If the `main` thread ends, it takes the other threads with it, done or not.

Comment: That's true in many ways am finding C easier to do multi threading than Java. I got the 4 senors operational although 1 seems to be less busy than the other 3. Did check the hardware and found no issue seems to be how the code is running. Thanks again been a real big help