# Counting Words in C with Multiple Threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I've asked this question before with an earlier/previous version of code but I already marked it as answered and I'm also not sure how best to update it so I'm asking again. I'm supposed to write a program on linux in C to count the words in a text file using multiple threads. The file has to be partitioned into multiple segments with each thread working on its own segment. So far I've come up with this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct threads
{
    int count;
    int pos;
} threads;


void partition_file(int n);
void *count_words();

int total_count = 0;
int seg_size = 0;
int pos = 0;
int num_threads = 8;

int main()
{
    int file=0;
    pthread_t tid[num_threads];
    threads threadsArray[num_threads];
    if((file=open("Device-Driver.txt",O_RDONLY)) < -1)
                return 1;
    close(file);
    partition_file(num_threads);

    pos = seg_size;

    for (int i=0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        threadsArray[i] = pos;
        pos += seg_size;
    }
    for (int i=0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, count_words, &threadsArray[i]);
    }
    for (int i=0; i < num_threads; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }
    printf("%d\n", total_count);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;

}

void partition_file(int n)
{
    int file=0;
    file=open("Device-Driver.txt",O_RDONLY);
    int size = lseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    seg_size = size / n;
    close(file);
}

void *count_words()
{
    int file=0;
    char buffer[seg_size];
    file=open("Device-Driver.txt",O_RDONLY);
    lseek(file,pos,SEEK_CUR);   
    read(file,buffer,seg_size);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);     
    for(int i = 0; i < seg_size; i++)
    {
        if(buffer[i] == ' ')
        {
            count += count + 1;          
        }
    }
    close(file);
}
```

- Line 37 (threadsArray[i] = pos) obviously gives me an incompatible types error but I'm not sure how else to do it
- I'm also not sure what *count_words() should look like now, specifically how to use the variables from the structure within *count_words()
- And I'm also not sure how to update total_count with the count from
  each thread

Comment: "It also has the requirement of if a word is divided into two parts, it should not be counted twice. How can I implement this?" can you elaborate on this or show us an example? I'm not sure what you mean by this

Comment: I think it might mean if part of a word is at the end of one segment/thread and the other is at the beginning of the next one. But I'm not entirely sure myself, it wasn't explained very well

Comment: Line 54: `if (buffer[i] == ' ')`  In C, double quotes are used for a string, and single quotes are used for character constants.

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that

Comment: Another problem is the use of `pos` in the threads. There's no guarantee that the thread will use its value of `pos`, before `main` changes the value of `pos`. Typically, you define a structure that has all of the information that a thread needs. Then create an array of those structures in `main`. Pass the address of one of those structures to the thread in the `pthread_create` call. [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32195821/3386109).

Comment: I see what you're saying but I'm not sure how well that would work because I also have to do different "versions" of the program where the number of threads is 16, 32, 64, and 128. And I'm not sure if I should really manually make an array of 128 values/value sets. Though I do also have the same problem with total_count, as the end value is radically different each time the program is run

Comment: It's not necessary to *manually* make the array. You can simply declare the array, and write code to fill in the values. As you are aware, the word count should definitely be part of the structure. Each thread should update it's own count, and then `main` should add up all of the counts when the threads have finished. You can use `pthread_join` in `main` to wait for the threads.

Comment: I've updated the code and have changed the code in my original question to reflect this and also the new errors. Also stackoverflow is warning me about extended conversation in comments

Comment: Line 37: should be two lines: `threadsArray[i].count = 0;` and `threadsArray[i].pos = pos;` The answer that I linked shows how to pass the array to the thread function. It also show how to "join" the threads so that `main` waits until all of the threads are finished.

Comment: I believe you've given me all the information needed to fix it up and finish it so thanks a lot. You should totally come to my college and be my new professor haha

Comment: Lol, glad I could help. Good luck!